# In jQuery, how do I trigger an action on a keypress but only if the focus is not on a form field?

Tags: jquery, events, keypress, form-fields

I’m using jQuery 1.11.  I want to run an action if the user presses the “d” key on the keyboard.  So I have this

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 68 || e.which == 100) {
        submitDownloadUsersReq();
    }
});
```

However, if they press the “d” key while within a text box, I don’t want the above action to be triggered.  How can I modify the above so that I will not trigger the action if the user is messing around with a form field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the type of element using `e.target` and `is()`:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is(':input') && (e.which == 68 || e.which == 100)) {
        submitDownloadUsersReq();
    }
});
```

Note that the `:input` selector will match `input`, `select`, `textarea` and `button`.

Comment: won't `this` points to document at this scenario? Correct me If I am wrong.'

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel the event when user is pressing `d` from an input element,

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(!$(e.target).is("input")) {
      if(e.which == 68 || e.which == 100) {
        submitDownloadUsersReq();
      }
    }
});
```